# Angularjs save items in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Found a code doing a to do list.

```
  $scope.tasks = [];
  $scope.searchEnter = function() {
  if(event.which == 13 && $scope.task !="") {
    $scope.addTask();
  };

};
$scope.addTask = function() {
  $scope.tasks.push({'taskMessage':$scope.task, 'done':false});
  console.log($scope.tasks);
  $scope.task = "";
};
$scope.clearCompleted = function() {
  $scope.tasks = $scope.tasks.filter(function(item){
    return !item.done;
  });
};
```

Was thinking about using it in a project where data is gathered from an API call.

How should data fetched with an API call be implemented into the to do list function? The data is in $rootScope.data and lets say it should be possible to store an attribute like data.id in the to do list.

Tried something like this without any results.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in data.list">
  <button ng-click="add()">Add!</button>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.done" />
     {{ x.id }}
    </td>
```

API call

```
    $scope.q ="";
$scope.searchData = function(url, id, callBack, apiCall, promise) {
  var url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q="+$scope.q+"&type=like";
  var id = APPKEY;
  var callBack = "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
  var apiCall = url + id + callBack;
  if($scope.q.length >= 3) {
    var promise = $http.jsonp(apiCall);
    promise.success(function(data){
      $rootScope.data = data;
      console.log($rootScope.data);
    });
  };
```

Want the users to be able to pick attributes and store them by their own liking.

Comment: how will be your data look like?

Comment: also add your api call implementation

Comment: can send tel about $rootScope.data? whr u are saving and assigning?

Comment: @sravan the data will be in json format.

Comment: it is an object, or an array?

Comment: both objects and arrays

Answer (score 1):

On promise success function,you assigned `data` to `$rootScope.data`.

What I have done is loop through that data and send every chunk of data to the `addTask` method.

That method pushes the data into the `tasks array` which you are displaying in the view.

As you said, I am assuming your response contains, array of objects.

**Update: Data returned from promise should be something like this,**

```
[
    {"id": 1, "name": "Test1"}
    {"id": 2, "name": "Test2"}
    {"id": 3, "name": "Test3"}
]


$scope.q ="";
$scope.searchData = function(url, id, callBack, apiCall, promise) {
  var url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q="+$scope.q+"&type=like";
  var id = APPKEY;
  var callBack = "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
  var apiCall = url + id + callBack;

  if($scope.q.length >= 3) {
    var promise = $http.jsonp(apiCall);

    promise.success(function(data){
      $rootScope.data = data;

      $scope.tasks = []

      $scope.addTask = function(data) {
        $scope.tasks.push(dara);
        console.log($scope.tasks);
      };


      for (var i = 0; i < $rootScope.data.length; i++)
            {
              $scope.addTask($rootScope.data[i])
            }

      $scope.addTask();
      console.log($rootScope.data);
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: explain please.  code only answers are not very helpful.

Comment: yes once, he implements this and comment something I can explain, any way I am adding the explanation

Comment: @cale_b, added some explanation, anyway thnk you for your suggestion.

Comment: $scope tasks logs undefined, might have something to do with how the data is structured?

Comment: exactly, data should be in `[
 {"id": 1, "name": "Test1"}
 {"id": 2, "name": "Test2"}
 {"id": 3, "name": "Test3"}
]` this format

Comment: my data looks like Object {message: "like", cod: "200", count: 11, list: Array[11]}
cod
:
"200"
count
:
11
list
:
Array[11]
0
:
Object
$$hashKey
:
"object:7"
clouds
:
Object
coord
:
Object
dt
:
1477150873
id
:
3675975
main
:
Object
name
:
"Los Patios"
sys
:
Object
weather
:
Array[1]
wind
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object